# Extracting three kinds of info on the same line with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, text

I have written a short script to extract certain data from a long text-file in Python. This the code.

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
if ( len(fname) < 1 ) : fname = 'test.v2'
rdf = open(fname)

import re
totalmoney = 0
totallent = 0
totaldebt = 0

for line in rdf:
    line = line.rstrip()
    money = re.findall('.*money=([0-9]*)', line)
    #lent = re.findall('.*money_lent=([0-9]*)', line)
    #debt = re.findall('.*debt=([0-9]*)', line)
    try: 
        money = int(money[0])
        totalmoney = totalmoney + money
        #lent = int(lent[0])
        #totallent = totallent + lent
        #debt = int(debt[0])
        #totaldebt = totaldebt + debt
    except: continue

print 'money total:',totalmoney
#print 'lent total:',totallent
#print 'debt total:',totaldebt
```

As you can see, the second and third meaningful data extractor lines are currently inactive (#), that is because when they are on it finds the value as zero, which I know is incorrect, because when I run them separately, they find a real value. I suspect that for some reason it cannot run all the three lines in the same loop, but I do not know why.

Could you please tell me how to extract three kinds of info from the same line?

Thanks.

Comment: Any sample of the file you are reading?

Comment: Your code works just fine for me (as in, all 3 regex statements return the expected values) in Python 3.4.4, but I had to make up what I think your data looks like.  To be certain, as @Grimmy suggests, please supply a sample of the file content you are reading.

Comment: Well, it is a file which is like 35000 lines long, so maybe I put it on dropbox so you can see it, otherwise I cant copy a sample here. Give me a sec.

Comment: Okay, so here is the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9b1acqnn329wf7u/test.v2?dl=0

Comment: You can open it with Notepad++ for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swallowing exceptions is not a good practice - you may never find out the reason why things go wrong. It is better not to swallow exceptions at all and do it right. This should work.

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
if ( len(fname) < 1 ): 
    fname = 'test.v2'
rdf = open(fname)

import re
totalmoney = 0
totallent = 0
totaldebt = 0

for line in rdf:
    line = line.rstrip()
    money = re.search('money=([0-9]*)', line)
    lent = re.search('money_lent=([0-9]*)', line)
    debt = re.search('debt=([0-9]*)', line)

    if money:
        totalmoney = totalmoney + int(money.group(1))
    if lent:
        totallent = totallent + int(lent.group(1))
    if debt:
        totaldebt = totaldebt + int(debt.group(1))

print('money total:',totalmoney)
print('lent total:',totallent)
print('debt total:',totaldebt)
```

Have fun playing Victoria 2 - I myself wasted a lot of time playing that game :)

Comment: Hello, thanks you that's great. it works :) 

now as you were playing Victoria 2 too, I wonder if you realized what I realized with the help of these python scripts. basically that the money has no explainable source. dou you perhaps know how it is possible that the first year there is like 172 million money, the next 272, and why debt and loans dont match?

Comment: Regrettably, I have no idea - probably the AI just cheats.